# How to add doubles from a string to an arraylist of doubles?

Tags: java

I have to add a student for each line in the students.txt file and also add the grades from it to the new student. The student object has 4 properties, name (string), last name(string), number(int), and grades (arraylist double)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class readFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        int linecnt = 0;
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("students.txt"))) {
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                
                students.add(new student("", "", 0));
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
                if(scan.hasNextDouble()) {
                    students.get(linecnt).addGrade(scan.nextDouble());
                }
                linecnt++;
                
            }
            
        }   catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        

    }

}
```

When I run this nothing happens, no errors, just a blank white space. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't see you print anything.

Comment: It's also possible that the loop has hung for some reason.  Try printing out some debugging statements, like each line read and then "Done." when the loop exits.

Comment: what are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 1):

You Have not said what should be the output.
The answer to your **question** is

> How to add doubles from a string to an arraylist of doubles?

```
String text = "12.34"; 
double value = Double.parseDouble(text);
arraylist.add(value);
```